# Cannot install awesomeversion==22.9.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies

Tags: python, pip

I've never done any Python so I'm not familiar with the package versions and dependencies system overall. I'm trying to run this repo https://github.com/Maaxion/homeassistant2influxdb

For this, I want to use Docker. So once I've cloned the repo, I've added this Dockerfile at the root and followed what was explained in the readme to the best I could:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt update -y

RUN apt install python3 python3.7-dev python3-venv python3-pip git -y

WORKDIR /home

COPY . .

RUN git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/home-assistant/core.git home-assistant-core

RUN python3 -m venv .venv

RUN . .venv/bin/activate

RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade --force pip

RUN pip3 install -r home-assistant-core/requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

It goes fine until it tries to install with pip3 with that line: `pip3 install -r home-assistant-core/requirements.txt` and I get:

```
Collecting atomicwrites-homeassistant==1.4.1

Downloading atomicwrites_homeassistant-1.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.1 kB)

ERROR: Cannot install awesomeversion==22.9.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:

The user requested awesomeversion==22.9.0

The user requested (constraint) awesomeversion==22.9.0

To fix this you could try to:

loosen the range of package versions you've specified

remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

I'm really not sure how to solve this despite taking a look at the link above...

Is it something to do with pip3? Have I missed something in the Dockerfile? How can I solve that issue? I've been looking online but there doesn't seem to be silver bullet answer for this kind of issues.

Could anyone provide some guidance? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try not to specify a direct version, like awesomeversion>=22.4.0 in your requirements.txt file.

Comment: This is the part where I'm confused, my requirementx.txt file is the following: influxdb
influxdb_client
mysqlclient
pyyaml
setuptools
tqdm
wheel

voluptuous
homeassistant

Comment: So I don't have any version in here

Answer (score 0):

What has probably happened is that one of the other requirements is specified as `coolRequirement >= somenumber`, (or just `coolRequirement`).

This means that pip is grabbing the latest recommended release for your python version. One of these requirements probably conflicts with something that `awesomeversion==22.9.0` requires. One possible solution would be to change `awesomeversion==22.9.0` to `awesomeversion>=22.9.0`, but that may not work if newer versions of `awesomeversion` break something else.

The real solution would be to figure out what versions of the other requirements worked in the past, and lock those down the same way that `awesomeversion` is specified.